# Free member log in is not working

Tags: expresso-store, freemember

Registration working but with this log in tag its not working , also checked browser network inputs both email and passwords are being passed

appreciate any help on this.

```
<div id="login" class="right">
              {if logged_out}
                {exp:freemember:login return='shop/checkout'}
                  <h2>Returning Customer</h2>
                  <p>I am a returning customer</p>
                  <b>E-Mail:</b><br>
                  <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" placeholder="User Email" maxlength="50" size="25">
                  {error:email}
                  <br>
                  <b>Password:</b><br>
                  <input class="password_input"  type="text" name="password" value="" placeholder="Your Password" maxlength="50" size="25">
                  {error:password}
                  <br>
                  <!-- <a href="{path='account'}">Forgotten Password</a><br> -->
                  <br>
                  <div class="sus-submit ">
                    <div class="submit_value"><input id="" class="" type="submit" value="Log In"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- <div class="welactauto"><input class="us-btn-orange" type="checkbox" name="auto_login" value="1" {auto_login_checked} /> Remember Me Here</div> -->
                {/exp:freemember:login}
              {/if}
              <br>
              <br>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of error or other output do you get?

Comment: Nothing its coming back to return page as if nothing happened. But error handling is working fine if i have given wrong and/or missing input in the two input.